# DidSelect a cell in Collection View implemented in Collection View cell

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

Have an issue with collection view cell.
i've got a collection view (vertical scroll) with 2 sections (1st is ServiceCell and the 2nd is OfferCell as ). First section is with 1 item - another collection view that is set in class ServiceCell: UIcollectionViewCell {} (horizontal scroll) with multiply subcells (ServiceSubCell).
i can't understand where i have to implement didselect method for subcells

main view conroller looks like this:

```
extension HomeScreenViewController: UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout {
    
    func numberOfSections(in collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int {
        2
    }
    
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        if section == 0 {
            
            return 1
        }
        return offers.count
    }
    
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        if indexPath.section == 0 {
            let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: ServiceCell.reuseId, for: indexPath) as! ServiceCell
            return cell
        }
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: OfferCellSubCell.reuseId, for: indexPath) as! OfferCellSubCell
        cell.backgroundColor = .white.withAlphaComponent(0.6)
        cell.layer.cornerRadius = 20
        cell.setup(with: offers[indexPath.row])
        return cell
    }
    
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        if indexPath.section == 0 {
// this part doesn't work
            let serviceVC = ServiceScreenViewController() as ServiceScreenViewController
            serviceVC.category = servicesCategoriesArray[indexPath.row]
            self.navigationController?.pushViewController(serviceVC, animated: true)
        } else {
            let offerVC = OfferScreenViewController() as OfferScreenViewController
            offerVC.offerNew = offers[indexPath.row]
            self.navigationController?.pushViewController(offerVC, animated: true)
        }
    }
}
```

Service cell with extension

```
class ServiceCell: UICollectionViewCell, UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout, UICollectionViewDataSource {
   
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return servicesCategoriesArray.count
    }
    
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: ServiceCellSubCell.reuseId, for: indexPath) as! ServiceCellSubCell
        cell.setup(with: servicesCategoriesArray[indexPath.row])
        return cell
    }
    
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    }
    
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
        return CGSize(width: 140, height: 140)
    }
    
}
```

Comment: Please can you add some code so that we can see more clearly what it is doing. Thanks

Comment: In the collectionView delegate. Most probably the cell in your case. But this can be the same collection view controller and for each dataSource /delegate method you test the collectionView passed as parameters. (You can set a tag in collectionView view to choose between main one and cell one.

Comment: @Fogmeister hello, added a code exxample

Answer (score 0):

You should implement "didSelect" in ServiceCell

and you should implement in your ViewController "should highlight" for first section to "false"

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, 
       shouldHighlightItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> Bool {
    return yourServiceSection ? false : true
}
```

the below code must be in ServiceCell and ViewController

```
 func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        collectionview.deselectItem(at: indexPath, animated: true)
 }
```

in your "ServiceCell" you must add this extension:

```
import Foundation
import UIKit

extension ServiceCell: UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout {
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return viewModel.list.count ?? 0
    }
    
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView,
                        cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier:
                                                        ServiceSubCell.nameOfClass,
                                                      for: indexPath) as? ServiceSubCell
        if let item = viewModel.data?.item(at: indexPath.item) {
            cell?.config(item: item)
        }
        
        return cell ?? UICollectionViewCell()
    }
    
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout,
                        sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
        return CGSize(width: SizeConstant.ServiceSubCellWidth.rawValue,
                      height: SizeConstant.ServiceSubCellHeight.rawValue)
    }
    
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        collectionview.deselectItem(at: indexPath, animated: true)
// implement your code you need
    }
}
```